# How to implement flexible login screen in Flutter?

Tags: authentication, flutter, dart, responsive-design

I'm implementing Login Screen but when the keyboard appears, many components are broken. Furthermore, if I use ListView to handle this, it is unnatural.

Therefore, I wanna do this like below. FLEXIBLE LOGIN SCREEN OF FACEBOOK.

[image]

Is there any hint on this implementation? I wanna show my source code which I tried, but it is a little complicated and I just wanna key point of this.

What I want to know

1. How can I detect TextField is selected or Keyboard appears?
2. I tried SliverAppBar but it is related only to ScrollView which is not proper to Login Screen, How can I do?

Comment: Looks like it could be done using a `SliverAppBar`. https://youtu.be/R9C5KMJKluE

Comment: @JordanDavies It is very difficult to me, any implementation?

Answer (score 1):

you can try **WillPopScope** widget. then on method call of **onWillPop** method replace the imageview with a smaller one. theres also some elegant solution like using silverappbar.

Comment: Too simple, more explanation

Comment: see this [example](https://pastebin.com/AE6qcV7c). havent got time to test it. but, it should work. sorry if it doesnt :) @baeharam

Comment: WillPopScope is not related to my question, it is about back button